# integrating linkedin into my application using scribe 1.3.1.jar

Tags: grails, linkedin-api, scribe

I am using scribe 1.3.1.jar.

I have successfully authenticated user with twitter using this jar.

But I am facing problem while authenticating user with linkedin using the same jar.

I am getting this error while obtaining access Token. I have successfully get request token & verifier.But the problem creeps when i tried getting access Token & got following exception:

Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this:

`oauth_problem=signature_invalid&oauth_problem_advice=com.linkedin.security.auth.pub.LoginDeniedInvalidAuthTokenException%20while%20obtaining%20request%20token%20for%20%3APOST%26https%253A%252F%252Fapi.linkedin.com%252Fuas%252Foauth%252FaccessToken%26oauth_consumer_key%253Dxuk04eooznqu%2526oauth_nonce%253D2417349075%2526oauth_signature_method%253DHMAC-SHA1%2526oauth_timestamp%253D1365577634%2526oauth_token%253D7277829e-e121-4b76-b0f4-8f5e9e6c7be8%2526oauth_verifier%253D66312%2526oauth_version%253D1.0%0AOAU%3Axuk04eooznqu%7C7277829e-e121-4b76-b0f4-8f5e9e6c7be8%7C%2A01%7C%2A01%3A1365577634%3AlCqOvqH1tkJAtpGa58tnEhqwdRQ%3D`

I feel really stuck in this.

Please Help!.

Comment: I can help you with this.  Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog post: http://www.objectpartners.com/2012/04/03/linkedin-api-in-a-grails-application/

It shows how to use the OAuth plugin which uses the Scribe library.  Hope that helps!